# Google Coral Dev Board: Fastboot is not found on path?

Tags: macos, tpu, fastboot, google-coral

I am trying to flash my google coral dev board on the macos. I learned that Catalina wouldn't function for using the board, so I downgraded to Mojave. Everything goes smoothly, except when I type the command

```
bash flash.sh
```

Onto my terminal in the process of flashing my board. The terminal returns the command:

> Couldn't find fastboot on your PATH -- did you install it?

I am sure I installed it. When I type fastboot devices or version on my terminal, it shows up correctly. And, when I echo path, this comes up

> /Users/name/Downloads/fastboot:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

So I am sure that it is on my path also. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new terminal and see if it is still in your path. If it is not in your path you can add it to ~/.bash_profile

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/.local/bin
```

Then when you open a new terminal it will still be in $PATH and bash flash.sh should work

Answer (score 0):

I faced the very same issue as you, and the way I could run *flash.sh* to ***"flash"*** my Coral dev was by modifying the file (*flash.sh*) and added the path where fastboot was located.

(I'm a Mac user) This is how I did it:

I went to check the version of fastboot (It also gives you where is the file located at)

```
cd ~/.local/bin
```

then:

```
./fastboot --version
```

Command results:

> fastboot version 30.0.4-6686687

> Installed as /Users/jegamboafuentes/.local/bin/./fastboot.

Then I went to the *flash.sh* file, open it and modify the line 19:

```
FASTBOOT_CMD="$(which fastboot)"
```

for:

```
FASTBOOT_CMD="/Users/jegamboafuentes/.local/bin/./fastboot"
```

I re-run, and **BOOM!** it worked, my Coral Dev Board was flashed.

Answer (score -1):

Check your model number using the reference [here](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started#1-initiate-fastboot-mode). If it was manufactured before April 10, 2019, then there are some steps for you to follow.

Similarly, make sure you download the latest fastboot version [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#downloads). Fastboot should be version 28.0.2 or higher. Hope this helps.